# What is the difference between component and bower?

Tags: components, bower, package-managers

I had a hard time finding an overview of the differences between [component](http://component.io) and [bower](http://bower.io). Which one is better, what is the better package manager to use? Are there any alternatives to these two I should consider?

Comment: I kind of found my answer here: http://dailyjs.com/2013/01/28/components/.


A discussion can be found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/componentjs/FGM46qQX9hs/zOryL24q1AcJ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A "component" is a part of a system. Bower is package manager.

Which one is better? Read [the Bower FAQ](https://github.com/bower/bower/wiki/FAQ) for differences.

Bower seems to make better what it aims for, that is a package manager for the web.

There are also Jam, Volo, or Ender. And of course, NPM.

For popularity and adoption check, you can [check Ohloh](https://www.ohloh.net/p/compare?project_0=Twitter+Bower&project_1=volo&project_2=isaacs%27s+npm)

UPDATE:

Component package manager https://github.com/component/component is also a package manager for the web. It uses GitHub as a back-end database for modules, so modules that are not on GitHub will not be listed. This approach however makes things easier, as there is no need for additional credentials; authors just use GitHub.

Personally, I think Component should adapt a distinctive name, so that it would be not confused with the general word "component."

Comment: "Component is part of a system." Based on this statement I don't think Joe understands the question. Yoshua is referring to https://github.com/component/component , a competitor to Bower.

Comment: For half a year the question was understood in the same way (6 votes up). Component package manager has ambiguous name.

Answer (score 4):

The team behind component have now written their own opinionated answer to this: https://github.com/component/guide/blob/master/component/vs.md#component-vs-bower

Copying the content as of today:

> Bower is more similar to `npm` than to Component. Like `npm`, Bower's `bower.json` manifest is inclusive except for everything in the relevant `.ignore` file. Component, on the other hand, is exclusive, downloading files only specified in the `component.json`.
>
> However, the major difference between Bower and Component is that `component.json`s are more strict and opinionated: all files listed in the `component.json` are **assumed to be mandatory**. On the other hand, files listed in a `bower.json` are generally optional.
>
> A strict manifest specification allows Component to easily integrate a build process. However, this is impossible with Bower as people publish different types of modules (globals, plugins, AMD, and CommonJS), as well as optional files as shown in this [react-bower issue](https://github.com/reactjs/react-bower/issues/1), making an integrated build process very difficult.
>
> Component's integrated build system allows you to simply include one script and one stylesheet in your page. There's no juggling `<script src="bower_components/jquery"><script>` calls and such.
>
> Like `npm`, `bower` is slower than Component at installing, has an unnecessary publish step, does not support multiple versions of dependencies, and does not cache installations.